# Emacs(AUCtex) can't recognize \input{~/Documents}

Tags: latex

I have three MacOSs, and set different names for **User** and **Home Folder**. I take Emacs as my default editor in those devices.

Using Emacs to edit tex-document, I found the code `\input{~/Documents}` and `\input{$HOME/Documents}` can't work when compiling, Error message said not found such file. To make it work, I must write the absolute path, such as `\input{/Users/Abel/Documents}` .

The trouble is due to the different account names and home folders in the three devices, I don't want to alter them into a same name. 
**Q:** Is there any method that keeping the situation and Emacs can recognize `\input{~/Documents}` or `\input{$HOME/Documents}` ?

Here  are some extra information:

1. Use other editors, such as TeXShop, this trouble doesn't happen both `\input{~/Documents}` and `\input{$HOME/Documents}` make effect.
2. `~/` can be known as Home directory by Emacs, typing `C+ x + f`, and `~/` , All Emacs(s) in devices point to the right Home Directory.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not an Emacs issue but a LaTeX issue. Note that `$HOME` works for me in a WSL-Ubuntu environment.

Comment: Wow, in my case, $HOME also works when I use a non-Emacs editor.

Comment: What is the value of `M-x getenv <RET> HOME <RET>`? If `HOME` is not in the environment of Emacs it cannot be passed to LaTeX. But, that case would be rather strange.

Comment: Emacs shows `/Users/abel/` , Abel is the name of HOME Folder.

Comment: The slash at the end of `HOME` is bad. Run `M-x setenv <RET> HOME <RET> /Users/abel <RET>` and try again.

Comment: @Tobias . Thank you! Now Emacs successfully compiles the Latex. 

The new trouble is `$HOME` makes the tex syntax highlighting fail to work due to the single `$`. 

My treatment is to add an extra `%$` behind  `\input{$HOME/Documents....` .

Comment: Under Linux I would now advise you to fix the HOME path in your `/etc/passwd` file. But, I do not know whether this advice is valid for MacOS. A hacky solution would be `(setenv "HOME" (directory-file-name (getenv "HOME"))` in your init file. I assume that is approximately what TeXShop does before running LaTeX.